# Video Player in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, video

I want to add a video player in as.net Mvc for playing videos. I have already tried JW Player, FlowPlayer, Video.js and JPlayer. The problem is no player shown video in chrome, firefox, and safari just playing audio with a blank screen. I have checked that video in IE and it work great and if i download video from chrome and play in vlc or window media player then it run perfectly. So, please let me know which player is best? I have also unchecked disable hardware acceleration option in chrome but no improvement shown in behavior. My video type is strictly mp4. So, please help .

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use the HTML5 video element.

```
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) for documentation and exaple

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Video.js. It is simple to inject into your asp.net application. Here is how:

1. Using Bower, install Video.js into your application
2. Reference the video.js javascript file and style sheet

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/video-js/video-js.css"/>

   <script src="~/lib/video-js/video.min.js"></script>
   ```
3. In your site.js file you can add this code so that every video tag will have the video.js player

   ```
   var VideoElements = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
   for (var i = 0; i < VideoElements.length; i++){
      videojs(VideoElements[i]).ready(function () {
         var myPlayer = this;
      });
   }
   ```