# How to save the progress of Video played using video control in asp.net mvc (C#)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html5-video

I am trying to find a way to save the progress of a video played using video control (HTML control) in asp.net MVC in an SQL database and later retrieve the state to check if the video was played fully or continue playing the video where it was stopped. I searched a lot but couldn't find any solution. Is there a way to achieve this? Kindly let me know.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140142/video-player-in-asp-net-mvc hope this post help you

Comment: @VinuthaN that post is just showing how to use the video control. What I want is to save the progress of video played at first time and then when the user exists from the page and returns back I want to use the saved progress to either continue playing it from where he stopped or check if the video was played fully.

Comment: <clientCache cacheControlMaxAge="07.00:00:00" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" /> in web config and refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251632/another-force-chrome-to-fully-buffer-mp4-video#18294706

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have found a solution. For a simple need, I am using  https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/av_event_ended.asp (For more media events refer, https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#mediaevents)